# Repetition Codeは日本語で何と言いますか？

Tags: coding-style

言語のサイトでは一般的な意味で答えるかソフトウエア工学知らないかもしれないからここに書く。

Repetition Codeは日本語で何と言いますか？

Repetition Codeは同じコードは一つの関数ではなくてあちこちに書く悪いソフトの書き方

Answer (score 2):

ご質問の内容は[Copy-and-paste programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-and-paste_programming)のことでしょうか。
もしそうならば、ソフトウェア業界では「同じコードは一つの関数ではなくてあちこちに書く悪いソフトの書き方」を多用する開発手法の**くだけた表現**として、英語と同様に「[コピペプログラミング](https://qiita.com/NagaokaKenichi/items/e855b944f4b427a911e8)」という呼称が用いられます。

他のご回答にある通りコード解析やレビューの視点から見ると「重複コード」という言い方がふさわしいです。
しかし日常会話や教育の場面では「コピペプログラミング」とこの手法を多用して開発する人に対して「コピペプログラマ」と皮肉を込めて表現する用例が散見されます。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。
ご指摘の意味であれば重複コード(Duplicate Code)と呼ぶことが多いと思います。Repetition Codeの訳は反復符号となりこれは、エラー修正(Error Correction)用の符号を表しています。

Hi, I suppose the word pointed out is '重複コード' in Japanese. We are using '反復コード' as the translated word of 'Reptation Code', And It means one of the codes for the error correction.

Answer (score 0):

こちらの「重複コード」または「コードクローン」ではないでしょうか？
[重複コード - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8D%E8%A4%87%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)

> 重複コード（ちょうふくコード、英: duplicate code）とは、ソースコード中に存在する同一、もしくは類似した部分のことである。コードクローンとも呼ばれる。

> 重複コードは、ソフトウェア保守を困難にする要因の一つである。その理由は、あるコードを修正したなら、そのコードの重複コード全てに対して修正の検討を行う必要があるからである。

> 1990年代後半から、主にソフトウェア工学の一環として、重複コードを検出する手法の研究が盛んに行われている。 ソフトウェア工学の分野では、重複コードは主にコードクローンと呼ばれる。

---

逆に「Repetition Code」は別の用途の言葉として使われているようなので、混同を避けるために重複コードを示すためには使わない方が良いかもしれません。
[反復符号 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%8D%E5%BE%A9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7)

> 反復符号（英: Repetition code）とは、ビットを反復することで伝送路上の誤りのない通信を実現する {\displaystyle (n,1)}{\displaystyle (n,1)} 符号化手法である。反復符号は非常に単純な符号化手法である。フェージングのある通信路では反復回数が多いほど誤り率が低下するが、ホワイトノイズが加算されるような通信路では逆に誤り率が高くなる。

Answer (score 0):

[英語版SOでrepetitive code(やrepetition code)を検索する](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=repetitive+code)と、どちらかというと [boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code)に近い意味合いで使われているのではないかと思いました。

"boilerplate code" は、日本でも大抵はそのまま "**ボイラープレートコード**" と呼ばれます。
"repetitive code" をそのまま日本語にすると… "**[くどい](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A9%E3%81%84)コード**" とかでしょうか…